# concurrent and background task in elixir?

Tags: concurrency, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a function in controller that sends massive text messages.(1000 messages)
controller function looks like this..

```
def send_sms(conn, _params) do
  // code is abbreviated
  # Spawn new process for sending message and saving to database
  spawn(fn -> send_message_and_save(user, recipients, phone_numbers) end)
  // code is abbreviated
end
```

and this function

```
def send_message_and_save(user, recipients, phone_numbers) do
    // code is abbreviated 
    results = Sms.send_sms_with_messaging_service_async(phone_numbers, recipients.message, msg_sid, status_callback, account, token)

    case Sales.confirm_order(recipients, attrs) do
      {:ok, %{id: order_id, user_id: user_id}} ->
        Messenger.create_message_status(results, order_id, user_id)
        # Update Bitly status as Saved
        if is_nil(recipients.bitly_id) do
        else
          bitly = Texting.Bitly.get_bitly_by_id(recipients.bitly_id)
          Bitly.confirm_changeset(bitly) |> Bitly.update()
        end
        {:ok, "Message sent successfully. Your analytics data will be updated shortly."}
      {:error, _changeset} ->
        {:error, "Can't send message!"}
    end
end
```

Job procedure is like this in send_message_and_save function
1. Send 1000 messages using external api request.
- I did this using Task.Supervisor.[async_stream/6](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#async_stream/6)
2. confrim_order (mark order schema as "confirmed" state and update (update)
3. create_message_status(create operation)
4. get_bitly_by_id(get operation)
5. Bitly.confirm_changeset and Bitly.update (update operation)

In this procedure, there will be total of 5000 database operation occurred.
and after making a request to external api request, there will be three status callback requests to my webserver for each of external api request.
That means, sending 1000 message will make 3000 thousands update operation to message_status schema(accept, delivered or undelivered).

So sending 1000 messages will end up 8000 database operation and I tried in this, my website becomes sluggish and and missing some of status callback request to my website due to timeout(external api says "There are many reasons a connection timeout can occur; common causes are long running database queries or outside processes and calls to external systems taking a long time to return")

So How can I improve this situation? how can I design this properly?
Please Help :(

Comment: Did you use `poolboy`to create a db connection pool?

Comment: How about using mq like `rabbitmq` to do this job?

Comment: Some databases support batch inserts, this can be very useful. You can use poolboy or manage your own pool of db connections so you aren't using just one connection. If it's an http api, you can still use a pool or just spawn a new process for every write/read.

Answer (score 0):

I would start off using [ETS as a cache](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/ets/) - you know all of the information you will need to pull from the DB up front, so go ahead and load it into memory.  Then you can spin up a process that will be responsible for the ETS table and you can make all future queries against that in memory table, which will be much faster than making multiple DB calls for each user you need to send a message to.  Do note that ETS tables are locally accessible only**, but if you wrap it in a process then that process will be globally available just like any other OTP process.

Many applications have a bottleneck at their database, so the less work you can give your database, the better (for many systems).

** locally means local to the node.  If you're running your application on only one server, then everything is local and you won't have to think about this much.  If you ever plan on clustering your application then you'll need to wrap the ETS table in a process with an API.  Processes have unique addresses across all clustered BEAM nodes so you can use that API to get access to the in memory table.  You can actually treat ETS as a faster redis, for most cases.  At a high level they are the same thing, but ETS uses erlang/elixir terms so it doesn't have the string serialization overhead that redis has, making it much faster.

Comment: Hey thanks for your advice. what about this solution? Using ets in GenServer for callback(that trigger 3 update operations for each message sent).

Comment: So instead update 3 times(queued, sent, delivered) to database, save each state in ets so when it is done(delivered or undelivered) just update database 1 time.

Comment: I think I misread your question earlier as meaning you were doing a lot of reads from the database as well, but if you're only doing writes, then yes the same principle would work.  It's much cheaper to write to ETS than to a database.  You could actually even save more work by batching up `delivered` database writes to only write once a minute or so.

Comment: Ok I will try this.. but get more questions. how long does ets table data persist? and how does ets table clean up in memory data?

Comment: ETS is an in memory table, but DETS can persist to disk.  I recommend reading all of the extensive documentation for any other information :)